# Adding CSV files to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, csv

I need to use the Add Join tool but before I can do that I must get the csv file into ArcMap. Yet when I go to ArcCatalog to try to add the csv it is not there. Also I tried using simply the add data button but again the csv is absent. So how can i get the csv file to show up in ArcCatalog so I can begin the process with the Add Join tool?

Comment: what do you mean absent? the file is not showing in catalog or the file is empty? refresh the root directory of the file and see if it appears. be sure its .csv file

Comment: You can try tool Make Table View with the csv as input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things to try:
Open the file in Excel; save a copy as a CSV. 
Open the file in notepad; save a copy as a CSV. 
Open the file in Excel; save a copy as a dbf. 
Open the file in notepad; save a copy as a dbf.
Create a file geodatabase; import the file into the geodatabase, then add it to the map from the geodatabase.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try, open CSV file in excel, save as excel file and use excel to table tool from Arcmap. Then try to join tables.

Answer (score 0):

I have just had a similar experience.

ArcMap cannot see CSV or DBF files in a OneDrive (cloud storage) folder, but can see them in a local (Downloads) folder.